# SQL-query to ActiveRecord-query. Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to write this SQL-query on ruby

```
SELECT value FROM CompanySetting WHERE company_id = 1 AND title = 'Work days'
```

and next get this value for the check, like this

value = ...SQL query... and then if value.nil?..

Can you help me write method which do this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a model `CompanySetting`, you can use the following to obtain the record with your conditions:

```
CompanySetting.where(company_id: 1, title: "Work days").pluck(:value)
```

If you just want the first record use:

```
CompanySetting.where(company_id: 1, title: "Work days").pluck(:value).first
```

If you want to test if a value is nil, you can use `value.nil?`

I suggest you read [some documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)

Comment: About rest of the question I bet there was meaning `value = ...SQL query...` and then `if value.nil?...`

Comment: that returned me all row from table. But need to get only one value from the column.

Comment: Use the `pluck` method in combination with `first` (see updated answer)

Comment: great! That's it! Tnx

Comment: Also: `CompanySetting.where(company_id: self.id, title:'Vacation days').first.value`

Answer (score 0):

val=CompanySetting.where(company_id: 1, title: "Work days").pluck(:value).first

"Do Something" if val.nil?